# How can I parse query string in WPF?

Tags: wpf, uri, frame, navigation-framework

hi I have wpf application. I created a pop up that act as container of pages being called.
the pop up has frame in which I just assign source for it to load. My prob is that I need to pass a query so I can retrieve it upon loading of the called page.

I have looked in google and most of the answers are saying use NavigationService.Navigate.CurrentSource.Query but the prob is Navigation is null when I use it.

activity flow:
When btn clicked = it calls window pop up show with some parameters.
pop up loads : selects which case to do according to passed param (see below). In the code below I want to pass the value  x as query.

My code:

```
 case PopUpModule.GALContinuingEduHistory:
                string x = "hello";
                lblHeader.Text = "GAL Continuing Education History";
                frmContent.Source = new Uri ("../Forms/FileMaintenance/Mediator/ContinuingEducHistoryPopUp.xaml?value=x",           UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                break;
```

Now my prob is how do I parse it when ContinuingEducHistoryPopUp.xaml loads?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `frame.Navigate(...)`?

Comment: thank u very much..it did the trick. i focused to much on .source method :)

Comment: Wasn't too sure, glad to help. I rewrote as answer then, as it's valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To use the Navigation framework, you should use:

```
frmContent.Navigate(new Uri ("../Forms/FileMaintenance/Mediator/ContinuingEducHistoryPopUp.xaml?value=x",           UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Note: you can also make use of [UriMapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.urimapper%28VS.95%29.aspx) to have simpler Uris in code.

Comment: that one works and was the exact answer I was looking. I ended up using it this way though (frmContent.Navigate(new ADR.Forms.FileMaintenance.Mediator.ContinuingEducHistoryPopUp(_currentAttorneyGAL));
) but both works the way I want it. :)